# Run chromium as different user - Cannot download files

Tags: linux, google-chrome, arch-linux, sudo, chromium

For security purposes, I'm running chromium with a UID different from my main desktop user.

```
user="web"
xhost +SI:localuser:"$user" > /dev/null
sudo -u "$user" -H -E -s -- chromium
```

With sudo configured to assume this users identity with NOPASSWD. This works nicely.
However, I can't download files in any way (regular downloads, 'save image as', exporting bookmarks etc.) any more: no 'save file' dialog appears.

I'm using chromium 43.0.2357.81. Downloading stuff worked in the past, but that was many months ago.
Removing */home/web/.config/chromium* (and thereby starting with a fresh profile) does not help. Running chromium with my main user does not suffer from this problem, so the problem must be related to running chromium with a different user.

The output on stdout mentions:

```
[11106:11123:0610/225419:ERROR:bus.cc(431)] Failed to connect to the
bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote
application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy
blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network
connection was broken.
[11106:11123:0610/225419:ERROR:power_save_blocker_x11.cc(285)] No
response to Uninhibit() request!
```

But I'm not too sure what to make of that.

I tried searching for a solution, and there are multiple results with chromium being unable to save anything. But those cases are all unrelated to my problem and trying those solutions does not help.

Does someone run a similar setup or has any ideas?